# How do I tell TypeScript that the result from the subscribe function is an array of x?

Tags: typescript, oop

I am having trouble with the concept of types while using noImplictAny and typescript with Angular 6. Basically the compiler is telling me that the type of result is Object while I know that the actual type will be an array of type Manufacturer. I can't assign the result to my manufacturers array because typescript is determined that the result is of type Object (which is implicitly any since it has no method signature).

How can I used noImplicitAny when I have no control over the typing of the result? Or do i?

```
interface Manufacturer {
  key:string;
  i18nName: string;
}


  public manufacturers:Manufacturer[];
  public manufacturersCollapsed: collapse[] = [];


  constructor(private http: HttpService) {

  }

  private getManufacturers() {
    this.http.get('manufacturers.json').subscribe(result => {
      console.log(result);
      this.manufacturers = result;
    });
}
```

Comment: Fix your `get` method to return a typed result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define the type like this

```
subscribe((result:Manufacturer[]) =>
```

Comment: Thank you. Typing concepts as still new to me, I attempted to do something like this `result<Manufacturer[]>` but obviously that is not the right syntax. I will accept the answer when I can.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use this notation:

```
this.http.get<Manufacturer[]>('manufacturers.json').subscribe(result => {
  console.log(result);
  this.manufacturers = result;
});
```